# Java generics - any way to avoid casts (and unchecked warnings) after I have called instanceof?

Tags: java, android, generics

Android code - the SharedPreferences class exports different methods for persisting/retrieving different preferences :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T retrieve(Context ctx, String key, T defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) return (T) (Boolean) prefs
            .getBoolean(key, (Boolean) defaultValue);
    else if (defaultValue instanceof Float) return (T) (Float) prefs
            .getFloat(key, (Float) defaultValue);
    // etc - another 4 cases
}
```

This works and I can call `boolean stored = retrieve(ctx, "BOOLEAN_KEY", true)` alright - but my question is : since I already used `instanceof` and `T` has boiled down to a specific class is there a way to avoid the single and double casts and the `warning : unchecked` ?

***EDIT*** : if I were to pass the class in I might as well call `getBoolean()` or `getFloat()` etc. What I want is to simplify the internals of the method and get rid of the warnings but still be able to call `retrieve(ctx, "KEY", 1 or "string" or true)` and get what I want back

Comment: Don't see a solution without reflection used to call `getXXX()` method based on which type `T` is. That would be a mess.

Comment: btw, you don't need to cast to both T and Boolean -- `(T) (Boolean)` can just become `(T)`. Pretty much any time you cast two things in a row like that, you can just cast to the last one. Remember that a cast just tells the compiler how to interpret the data, which is unchanged. What you wrote says "take this boolean, interpret it as a Boolean, then interpret it as a T". You can just say "take this boolean and interpret it as a T"

Comment: @yshavit: wrong - I can't

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I must have misremembered the precise specs on autoboxing, sorry.

Comment: @yshavit: you can't cast a primitive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cast after an instanceOf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186320/why-cast-after-an-instanceof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my question <del>is</del> was (simply) : *since I already used instanceof and T has boiled down to a specific class is there a way to avoid the single and double casts and the warning : unchecked ?*

And the answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186343/281545) - I am quoting this particular answer cause it shows I am not the only one who wondered. But you may wish to vote the interesting albeit a bit off topic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305136/281545) by @yshavit :)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you can't get rid of the warnings. They're there for a reason.

Longer answer: As you may know, generics in Java are just syntactic sugar plus compile-time checks; pretty much nothing survives to runtime (a process known as "erasure"). This means that the cast to `(T)` within your method is actually a no-op. It'll turn into a cast to the most specific type that it can be, which in this case is `Object`. So this:

```
(T) (Boolean) prefs.whatever()
```

really turns into this:

```
(Object) (Boolean) prefs.whatever()
```

which is of course the same as just:

```
(Boolean) prefs.whatever()
```

This can get you into a dangerous situation, which is what the warnings are trying to tell you. Basically, you're losing type safety, and it can end up biting you far away from where the bug actually is (and thus be hard to track down). Imagine the following:

```
// wherever you see "T" here, think "Object" due to erasure
public <T> void prefsToMap(String key, T defaultValue, Map<String, T> map) {
    T val = retrieve(this.context, key, defaultValue);
    map.put(key, val);
}

Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
prefsToMap("foo", 123, map);
// ... later
Integer val = map.get("foo");
```

So far so good, and in your case it'll work, because if "foo" is in the prefs, you'll call `getInt` to get it. But imagine if you had a bug in your `retrieve` function, such that `if( defaultValue instanceof Integer)` accidentally returned `getDouble()` instead of `getInt()` (with the casting and all that). The compiler won't catch it, since your cast to `T` is really just a cast to `Object`, which is always allowed! You won't find out until `Integer val = map.get("foo");`, which becomes:

```
Integer val = (Integer) map.get("foo"); // cast automatically inserted by the compiler
```

This cast could be very far away from where the error really happened -- the `getObject` call -- making it hard to track down. Javac is trying to protect you from that.

Here's an example of it all put together. In this example, I'll be using a `Number` instead of a prefs object, just to keep things simple. You can copy-paste this example and try it out as is.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getNumber(Number num, T defaultVal) {
        if (num == null)
            return defaultVal;
        if (defaultVal instanceof Integer)
            return (T) (Integer) num.intValue();
        if (defaultVal instanceof String)
            return (T) num.toString();
        if (defaultVal instanceof Long)
            return (T) (Double) num.doubleValue(); // oops!
        throw new AssertionError(defaultVal.getClass());
    }

    public static void getInt() {
        int val = getNumber(null, 1);
    }

    public static void getLong() {
        long val = getNumber(123, 456L); // This would cause a ClassCastException
    }

    public static <T> void prefsToMap(Number num, String key, T defaultValue, Map<String, T> map) {
        T val = getNumber(num, defaultValue);
        map.put(key, val);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String,Long>();
        Long oneTwoThree = 123L;
        Long fourFixSix = 456L;
        prefsToMap(oneTwoThree, "foo", fourFixSix, map);
        System.out.println(map);
        Long fromMap = map.get("foo"); // Boom! ClassCastException
        System.out.println(fromMap);
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

- **The big one:** Even though generics are supposed to give me type-safety, I got a ClassCastException. And not just that, but I got the error in a section of code with no errors at all (`main`). The error happened in `prefsToMap`, but `main` paid the cost. If the `map` were an instance variable, it could be *very* hard to track where that error was introduced.
- Other than using a Number instead of a prefs, my `getNumber` is pretty much the same as your `retrieve` function
- I intentionally created a bug: if `defaultVal` is a `Long`, I get (and cast to `T`) a *double* instead of a long. But the type system has no way of catching this bug, which is exactly what the unchecked cast is trying to warn me about (it's warning me that it can't catch any bugs, not that there necessarily are bugs).
- If `defaultValue` is an int or String, everything will be fine. But if it's a Long, and the `num` is null, then I'll be returning a `Double` such when the call site expects a `Long`.
- Because my `prefsToMap` class only casts to `T` -- which, as mentioned above, is a no-op cast -- it won't cause any cast exceptions. I don't get an exception until the second-to-last line, `Long fromMap = map.get("foo")`.

Using `javap -c`, we can see how some of these look in bytecode. First, let's look at `getNumber`. Note that the casts to `T` don't show up as anything:

```
public static java.lang.Object getNumber(java.lang.Number, java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   ifnonnull   6
   4:   aload_1
   5:   areturn
   6:   aload_1
   7:   instanceof  #2; //class java/lang/Integer
   10:  ifeq    21
   13:  aload_0
   14:  invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/Number.intValue:()I
   17:  invokestatic    #4; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   20:  areturn
   21:  aload_1
   22:  instanceof  #5; //class java/lang/String
   25:  ifeq    33
   28:  aload_0
   29:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/Object.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   32:  areturn
   33:  aload_1
   34:  instanceof  #7; //class java/lang/Long
   37:  ifeq    48
   40:  aload_0
   41:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/lang/Number.doubleValue:()D
   44:  invokestatic    #9; //Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
   47:  areturn
   48:  new #10; //class java/lang/AssertionError
   51:  dup
   52:  aload_1
   53:  invokevirtual   #11; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   56:  invokespecial   #12; //Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   59:  athrow
```

Next, take a look at `getLong`. Notice that it casts the result of `getNumber` to a `Long`:

```
public static void getLong();
  Code:
   0:   bipush  123
   2:   invokestatic    #4; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   5:   ldc2_w  #15; //long 456l
   8:   invokestatic    #17; //Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
   11:  invokestatic    #13; //Method getNumber:(Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   14:  checkcast   #7; //class java/lang/Long
   17:  invokevirtual   #18; //Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
   20:  lstore_0
   21:  return
```

And finally, here's `prefsToMap`. Notice that since it only deals with the generic `T` type -- aka Object -- it doesn't do any casting at all.

```
public static void prefsToMap(java.lang.Number, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.util.Map);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_2
   2:   invokestatic    #13; //Method getNumber:(Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   5:   astore  4
   7:   aload_3
   8:   aload_1
   9:   aload   4
   11:  invokeinterface #19,  3; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.put:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   16:  pop
   17:  return
```

Comment: I will go through your updated answer (which I just saw but have a look at this : http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=4385173GENERICS.jpg. So no : "It'll turn into a cast to the most specific type that it can be, which in this case is Object". This receive() is just `<T> T retrieve(String key, T value) {
  return AccessPreferences.retrieve(this, key, value);
 }` where the AccesPrefs.receive is the function in question

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Not 100% sure what you mean by your comment, sorry. Are you saying that the IDE says it'll add a cast within the method? If so... it won't. In your screen shot, it'll add a cast at the call site. So, `haveEnabledWifi` will become `return (Boolean) retrieve(HAVE_ENABLED_WIFI_PREF_KEY, false)` which is just what you want. But above, I show an example where the call site _won't_ insert a cast (because the call site is itself generic), causing you to be able to corrupt a `Map`. Basically, it's hard for javac to prove when a cast to `T` is safe, so it plays it conservative.

Comment: In a hurry - It's not the IDE - it's javac who says so, ofc. Eclipse does not implement its own compiler. It's javac who sees this as returning Boolean - not Eclipse. And it will be compiled like this. In your answer you forgot to add the use of map in `prefsToMap`. Also - if your scenario with getObject were true I bet you'd get Unsafe cast from Object to Integer in `Integer val = (Integer) map.get("foo");`. Maybe try it out ? (and think that this is really not my biggest dark spot in generics and my class :)

Comment: Eclipse does have its own compiler, or at least used to! But it's not that at issue, it's the JLS itself. And to be clear, that `Integer val = (Integer)...` line isn't anything you'd write, it's what javac/ecj will insert when you have `Map<String,Integer> map = whatever(), Integer val = map.get("foo");` I think you and I may be talking at cross paths here. :)

Comment: Cross paths ? what's that ? My English fails me - anyway I know eclipse has an incremental compiler but what it shows in the pic it's what the code will get compiled to by javac. Consider : if `whatever()` is of type `Map<String, Object>` which will be if you call `prefsToMap("foo", new Object(), map);` (edit prefsToMap) you will get a warning in line `Integer val = map.get("foo");` _exactly because the compiler is about to add the cast_. If your map is not `Map<String, Object>` you will get the warning in the line `prefsToMap("foo", new Object(), map);`. Please test with a dummy getObject

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I meant "talking at cross purposes," sorry. Basically, we're saying different things. I'll update my answer in a couple minutes with more specifics.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I just edited the answer to explain why the warning has to be there -- I wrote code that suppresses the warning but has a type-safety bug in it, and demonstrated how it can blow up.

Comment: Now that's a +1 - I understand all your points but will study this asap - I do understand what the warnings is about but the bytecode is certainly interesting. Just to clarify : what was my point in the comments is that once `retrieve` had no bugs I am sure the client code is typesafe - and my original question was about simplifying the internals of retrieve

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Ah, okay. Yes, we're in agreement, then. The unchecked warning is basically Java's way of saying the type system can't help you anymore, but you're right that there are times you can still be sure it's type safe.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way is to use the Class.cast(obj), biut you will need an instance of the T Class, this is typically done by passing one in to the method, but in your case will be fine:

```
return Boolean.class.cast(pregs.getBoolean(key, (Boolean)defaultValue));
```

EDIT: After the comment, yes, it could be a problem with the type mismatch.

You will need to pass in the class type as part of your method, or infer it from the default value (if it is not null:

```
return defaultValue.getClass().cast(pregs.getBoolean(key, (Boolean)defaultValue));
```

Editing again with working example (this works wihtout any warnings for me):

```
public class JunkA {

    private boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean def) {
        return def;
    }

    private float getFloat(String key, float def) {
        return def;
    }

    private String getString(String key, String def) {
        return def;
    }

    private int getInt(String key, int def) {
        return def;
    }

    public <T> T getProperty(final Class<T> clazz, final String key,
            final T defval) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)) {
            return clazz.cast(getBoolean(key, (Boolean) defval));
        }
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            return clazz.cast(getString(key, (String) defval));
        }
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)) {
            return clazz.cast(getFloat(key, (Float) defval));
        }
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
            return clazz.cast(getInt(key, (Integer) defval));
        }
        return defval;
    }

}
```

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#4-of ? extends Object to T"

Comment: See my edit - this could work if I could get `clazz` from `defval`somehow (instead of passing it in) - notice that `defval` may be  primitive. Anyway I could do that ? (correct the typos and avoid blank lines btw - it just make people scroll - make your `getXXX` one liners - once there are scrollbars you have posted too much code for a site like this :)

Comment: With a single 'unhecked' warning, and the guarantee that defaultValue is not null,  you can: Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)defaultValue.getClass();