# Generic array casting for Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, objectinputstream

I just started playing with Generics because I thought it would be a good learning experiment. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get my code to work. I'm having several problems:

1. How do I correct the `ClassCastException`? 
 2. Why does `ois.readObject()` return an array of `Object`s when it only has a return type of just Object? Is this some sort of fancy loop?
 3. How do I fixed the unchecked warning Eclipse is giving me?

```
public foo<T> {
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo"));
   ...
   public T[] foo() {
       try {
            return (T[]) ois.readObject(); // Eclipse "unchecked" warning
       } catch (Exception e) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: 3. You can't. You might end up reading any type of object from the stream.

Comment: 2. `Object[]` is a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: 1. Hard to say, since we don't know what different things you are trying.

Comment: Slightly annoying to get your head around the fact that `Object[]` is a subclass of `Object` I must say.

Comment: @AndyTurner Not even through the use of the method `instanceOf(T)`?

Comment: @DavidFisher no. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16304609/3788176

Comment: @AndyTurner 1. I'm just looking to correct it. If I read the file without the use of generics I don't have a problem reading the file and have access to all of the data.

Comment: @DavidFisher you cant check `instanceof T` as `T` is not known at compile time

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you -- I actually didn't search for that question. I appreciate that.

Comment: Correct *what*, exactly? You are saying this code fails in different ways when you try different things; it is necessary to know exactly what it is you are trying to create these failures.

Comment: @DavidFisher The closest you can get to an `instanceof` check is to pass a `Class<T>` instance to foo. Then you can do `if (clazz.isInstance(object)) t = (T) object;`. However this still generates a warning and is still dodgy if `T` is itself a generic type.

Comment: @AndyTurner Unfortunately, I cannot recall all the different things I had tried to make this work. I do know that I have tried numerous different things including `Object` arrays in place of generics, passing a generic through the method, calling the method through the class (static) and through an object.

Comment: @AndyTurner is #2 unclear? I see a lot of comments about `Object[]` being a subclass of `Object`. That's fine but if that's true than why can I not type cast to `foo[]` if it's also a subclass of `Object` using the generics this should work

Comment: @DavidFisher it's quite simple: you might be able to cast the `Object` returned by `ois.readObject()` to a `T[]`, but you might not - there is no way to know that it won't return you a `String`. The compiler cannot guarantee that will definitely not fail (or definitely fail). As such, it gives you an unchecked cast warning.

Comment: @AndyTurner the file is full of `String` objects (an array) then `ois.readObject()` can return `Object[]` but it should also be able to return `String[]`. Do you have a suggestion on how I can write this? I adding each object to an ArrayList and then using the method toArray and received a similar error, `Object[]` cannot be cast to `Foo[]`.

Comment: @DavidFisher No. If the file is full of `String` objects then each call to `ois.readObject()` will return an `Object` which can be cast to `String`. It cannot return an `Object` which can be cast to `String[]` because `String[]` is not a subtype of `String` and nor is `String` a subtype of `String[]`. There is no "fancy loop" here. You simply get what is next in the stream, nothing else.