# Checking if an object from ObjectInputStream is a particular type

Tags: java, sockets

Hi guys I want to do something like

```
if((Color[])objectIn2.readObject() instanceof Color[]){
     //do something
}
```

but this does not seem to work, so how can I do something similar ?
objectIn2 would be an objectinputStream

Comment: What you are doing now is objectIn2.readObject(), cast the result to Color[] and then check if that Color[] is a Color[]....

Comment: Do you want to keep the object or just check it's type?

Answer (score 6):

You're casting, and checking if you can safely cast, at the same time. Check before casting instead:

```
Object o = objectIn2.readObject();
if (o instanceof Color[]) {
    Color[] colors = (Color[]) o;
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Works like this:

```
if(objectIn2.readObject() instanceof Color[]){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: This just checks the type and throws it away.

Comment: Except now, he can't get its color array anymore.

Comment: but maybe thats all he wants, since he's doing the same thing in his post ;-) Of course he can save the object first, and check then.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
    object p = objectIn2.readObject();
    Color[] c;

    if(p instanceof Color[]){
    //Do somthing
        c = (Color[]) p;
}
```

More information:

[Why cast after an instanceOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186320/why-cast-after-an-instanceof)

Comment: but then wouldnt it be an object and not a Color[] ?, i assumed that readObject returned an object and so i had to cast it as a Color[] before using it as a Color[] ?

Comment: Ok,but why does this not work: if(objectIn2.readObject() instanceof Color[])a = (Color[]) objectIn2.readObject(); and this work: a = (Color[]) objectIn2.readObject; i.e without the if

Comment: @JohnCollins read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186320/why-cast-after-an-instanceof

Comment: Thanks for the info but when it has the if statement in front I get an 'Invalid type code: 30' I searched but couldn't find anything what is it ?